# Will 260F damage my engine or cause AC leak

Tags: ac, overheating, heat

I went mudding in my jeep. It was really soupy and coated the entire engine bay including the rad. Didn't wash off the mud and then drove downhill into town a few days later Didn't realize temps until the return uphill trip. Temps pegged the gauge just below 260F for a solid hour. I smell a strange synthetic smell now in the engine bay near my AC components but another than that the engine runs fine. Its a straight 6 inline engine with about 190K miles on it. Does that sounds like an AC leak? Should I be worried about other components? There is no smoke coming from the engine or the tail pipe so I think my head is good.

Comment: Did the a/c operate correctly before going mudding? Does it operate correctly now?

Comment: There's no reason to suspect an AC issue, it could just be the mud getting cooked. Try washing it all off and seeing if that solves the issue.

Comment: It worked but the AC system had a leak somewhere before all this. I smell it coming from the compressor. Its not the mud as its not coming from anywhere else and I can smell it when the car is off. I think its the compressor oil that I'm smelling. I haven't tried the AC but its time to replace the system. Its 25 years old and the condenser is already packed full of bugs and now mud.  I was kind of wondering if any of you had experience with running an engine this hot before and if it caused permanent damage or not. I'm gonna do a compression check but other than that I'm not sure what to do.